# How to efficiently compare each row of a matrix to each section of a list in R?

Tags: r, performance, list, matrix, comparison

Here's an example of what I mean, this code outputs the right thing:

```
list1 = list(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7), c(8,9), c(10, 11))
matrix1 = rbind(c(1,2), c(1,5), c(8, 10))

compare <- function(list.t, matrix.t) {
    pairs <- 0
    for (i in 1:nrow(matrix.t)) {
         for (j in 1:length(list.t)) {
              if (length(intersect(matrix.t[i,], list.t[[j]])) == 2) {
                         pairs <- pairs + 1
              }
         }
    }
    return(pairs / nrow(matrix.t))
}

compare(list1, matrix1) 
# = 0.33333
```

I hope that makes sense. I'm trying to take an nx2 matrix, and see if the two elements of each row of the matrix are also found in each section of the list. So, in the example above, the first row of the matrix is (1,2), and this pair is found in the first section of the list. The (1,5) or the (8,10) pairs are not found in any section of the list. So that's why I'm outputting 0.3333 (1/3).

I'm wondering if anyone knows a way that doesn't use two for-loops to compare each row to each section? I have larger matrices and lists, and so this is too slow.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this work just the same?  You could call `sapply` over the list and compare with all rows of the matrix simultaneously.

```
> list1 = list(c(1,2,3,4), c(5,6,7), c(8,9), c(10, 11))
> matrix1 = rbind(c(1,2), c(1,5), c(8, 10))

> s <- sapply(seq_along(list1), function(i){
      length(intersect(list1[[i]], matrix1)) == 2
  })
> sum(s)/nrow(matrix1)
# [1] 0.3333333
```

If we call your function `f1()`, and this `sapply` version of the same function `f2()`, we get the following difference in speed.

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq  median       uq      max neval
#  f1() 245.017 261.2240 268.843 281.7350 1265.706   100
#  f2() 113.727 117.7045 125.478 135.6945  268.310   100
```

Hopefully that's the increase in efficiency you're looking for.

Comment: Greater degree of vectorization. And I think easier to understand as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is offered in the spirit of your R golf challenge for your problem, a compact bu potentially inscrutable solution:

```
mean( apply(matrix1, 1, 
          function(x) any( {lapply(list1, function(z) {all(x %in% z) } )}) )
     )

[1] 0.3333333
```

The inner lapply tests whether a particular element of `list1` has both of the items in the two-element vector pass as a row from `matrix1`. Then the `any` function tests whether any of the 4 elements met the challenge for a particular row. The intermediate logical vector `c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)` is converted into a fraction by the `mean`. (It still really two nested loops.)